# Java JpaSystemException Can't execute statement

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, exception

I want add new user to DB.
When i was creating db ID was set as autoincrement, not null(email,password also)

Here is my user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class User{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@NotNull
@Email
private String email;

@Column(name = "phone_number")
private String phoneNumber;



@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
private RoleDAO roleDAO;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Ticket> tickets;
```

User relates to other entity RoleDAO. So code of it is next

RoleDAO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class RoleDAO {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "role")
private String role;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="roleDAO")
private List<User> users;
```

i've got:

```
"exception": "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException",
"message": "could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement",
```

Any idea?

**UPDATED**

```
2018-05-04 15:09:57.775 ERROR 5012 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause



java.sql.SQLException: Field 'role' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdb
c.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.edsson.expopromoter.api.service.UserService.create(UserService.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.edsson.expopromoter.api.controller.AuthController.registration(AuthController.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.edsson.expopromoter.api.controller.AuthController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a58f74db.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

this appears after

```
 RoleDAO roleDAO = roleService.findRoleDAOByRole(RolesConfiguration.ROLE_USER);
 userService.create(new User(registrationRequest.getEmail(),registrationRequest.getPassword(), roleDAO  ));
```

I've added full stack trace. This appears when i call userRepository.save which inside userService.create

**One way to fix**

Add default value for this column in db. My user has default value ROLE_User. So i've put it in.

I've still want to know other resolutions

Comment: What's your DB? Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: It's Mysql DB//

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace in your server?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know how to get full stacktrace. This error i get from postman post method /registration as an answer.

Comment: Do you have local server? Then open the server console / log file to read the exception

Comment: Added, but not full

Comment: It would seem the `USER` table, or one of the tables corresponding to a related entitiy, has a non-nullable `role` column, and you didn't provide a value for that column. BTW What is `RoleDao`, and why is its join column named `id`?

Comment: RoleDAO is entity table for "role"
User has foreign key "role" this relates to table roles->field id

Comment: I've edited again. Please check

Comment: It relates to your `RoleDAO` class. Please post it here

Comment: Posted, please check.

Comment: Have you checked the field `role` in your database? It might be null?

Comment: it's pointed as notNull in DB. 
I've already tried to add @NotNull annotation to RoleDAO entity. Problem was the same

Comment: Did you check the value of `role` in roleDao returned from `roleService.findRoleDAOByRole(RolesConfiguration.ROLE_USER)`? Looks like it is not available and database doesnt know what value to set.

Comment: It returns valid value